# .NET, CustomObject named in package.xml but was not found in zipped directory

Tags: metadata-api, .net, deployment

I have successfully retrieved my package with the metadata api.

If I deploy said package with deployOptions.singlePackage=false, I get a successful deployment, with 0 components deployed. I've also done this with minor changes to an .object file ( added a custom field ) to test changes. Still 0 components deployed, no changes to org.

With singlePackage=true, I get errors of "CustomObject xxxxx was specified in package.xml but was not found in the zipped directory".

Since I packaged the retrieved components in the same directory structure that was retrieved, I would have expected it to be successful. I have also tried other directory structures.

The retrieved directory structure that I zipped and tried to deploy was:

```
/unpackaged
   package.xml
   /objects
   /permissionsets
```

with xml files in /objects and /permissionsets. Is this the correct zip directory structure? I'm using .net Compression.Zipped.Create to zip. The source for the zip function is a folder which contains /unpackaged, which results in the zip containing the unpackaged directory.

I'm pretty much stuck with this deploy function.  Any suggestions? Would the create(), update() functions be easier to use?

Comment: I'm using the Partner and Metadata WSDL files.  I've added them as a WebReference in my .NET project

Comment: You can edit your own question for clarification, even when you can't edit any arbitrary question. I suggest you do so as an edit.

Comment: @cfann61 Should the second paragraph be "If I deploy said package with deployOptions.singlePackage=**true**"? That, or it should be true in the third paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

The zip file (bytes) that you pass to the deploy method should **not** contain the /unpackaged folder. `package.xml`, `/objects`, and `/permissionsets`  should be in the root of the zip.

You should also set singlePackage to true.

Comment: When I structure the zip like this, I'm getting errors "An object xxxx of type CustomObject was named in package.xml, but was not found in zipped directory."  I have unzipped the deploy.zip to check the contents, and it contains the .object files referenced.

Comment: Try changing you package.xml file to use the * notation for each type. Then it will deploy exactly what is included in the zip file.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all of the components listed in the package.xml file are in the directories, I'd say the solution is to set singlePackage to true.

There might be another error somewhere else, but when deploying unpackaged metadata to salesforce, in my experience, that value always needs to be set to true.